# how to Redirect form submmit

Tags: php, redirect, newsletter

I create a newsletter I want to redirect after submitting the form
my PHP saving the emails to MySQL Server but not redirecting to new page
here my PHP code is

```
<?php
include_once("Config.php");
$email_access = new Config();
if(isset($_POST['email_data_values'])){
    $n_email = $_POST['email_data_values'];
    $email = $email_access->htmlfilter($n_email);
    if(preg_match('/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/', $email)){
        $email_field['email'] = $email;
        $email_check = $email_access->email_exits("email",$email_field);
        $redirect_url = "https://www.rambletravels.in/win/";
        if($email_check){
            $insert = $email_access->insert("email",$email_field);
            if($insert){
                echo "You email is Registered Speen to Win Prize ";
                header("Location: $redirect_url");
            }
            else{
                echo "Not Subscribed";
                return false;
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "You Have Already entered For Prize";
            return false;
        }
    }
    else{
        if(!preg_match('/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/', $email)){
            echo "Please Enter a Valid Email";
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have output `echo` before the `header`.
More details on [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)